# React contentEditable div with controlled input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, contenteditable

Is there any way to have a controlled input contentEditable div?

I am looking for this exact behavior, but I need to use a contentEditable div instead of an input:

```
<input value={this.state.text}></input>
```

where the input doesn't show what is typed, but rather what is in `this.state.text`.

Just swapping out with a contentEditable div doesn't work, and it shows what is typed rather than what is in `this.state.text`:

```
<div contentEditable={true} value={this.state.text}></div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q4xoya

Comment: Try this in your stackblitz: `<div style={{border: '1px solid black'}} contentEditable={true}>{this.state.text}</div>`

Comment: That displays `this.state.text` initially, but stops if typed in. I updated the stackblitz @RobMoll

Comment: Yes. It changes if you type in the div, but not if you type in the input. Not sure what your intent is.

Comment: My intent was for it to behave exactly like the input (I am just replacing some inputs with contenteditable divs because I need more control of styling and events). However, I think I should be able to make it work how I want by doing what you suggested and adding some extra events other places in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is not a valid attribute for a `div`. It can be done, but is not officially supported and is certainly unorthodox.

I suggest you change this line from your stackblitz:

```
<div style={{border: '1px solid black'}} contentEditable={true} value={this.state.text}></div>
```

to this:

```
<div style={{border: '1px solid black'}} contentEditable={true}>{this.state.text}</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make it behave exactly like the input, but it is probably the best option and I can make it work with some workarounds elsewhere. Thanks again!